# Scalacheck always generates the same UUID for an arbitrary of List[UUID]

Tags: scala, uuid, scalacheck

I'm trying to generate a list of arbitrary UUIDs using scalacheck (version 1.12.2). For some reason, every UUID in the generated list is the same. This is not the case for other types such as List[String] or List[Int]. Here is the code I've written:

```
import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary.arbitrary
import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary
import java.util.UUID

case class SomeUUIDClass(field: List[UUID])
case class SomeOtherClass(field: List[Int])

object Arb {
    implicit def arbUUID: Arbitrary[UUID] = Arbitrary {
        UUID.randomUUID()
    }

    implicit def arbUUIDClass = Arbitrary {
        for {
            field <- arbitrary[List[UUID]]
        } yield SomeUUIDClass(field)
    }

    implicit def arbOtherClass = Arbitrary {
        for {
            field <- arbitrary[List[Int]]
        } yield SomeOtherClass(field)
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("without uuids:")
        arbitrary[SomeOtherClass].sample.get.field.foreach(println(_))
        println("")

        println("with uuids:")
        arbitrary[SomeUUIDClass].sample.get.field.foreach(println(_))
    }
}
```

And a sample run:

```
without uuids:
-1
0
2147483647
-1
-2147483648
527079214
-698179980
1192016877
-1001957700
0
682853458
-1
-2147483648
109314552
1130736291
1080418
1771214863
1164874892
-1306566270
2147483647
-2009106057
2147483647
-2147483648
-1
-1
-1
945958506
777623735
-490377345
-272177229
0
-2147483648
-1753697474
-1
736327057
415072340
0

with uuids:
a49540b4-29ce-464f-946d-3649f38fb8a6
a49540b4-29ce-464f-946d-3649f38fb8a6
a49540b4-29ce-464f-946d-3649f38fb8a6
a49540b4-29ce-464f-946d-3649f38fb8a6
a49540b4-29ce-464f-946d-3649f38fb8a6
a49540b4-29ce-464f-946d-3649f38fb8a6
a49540b4-29ce-464f-946d-3649f38fb8a6
a49540b4-29ce-464f-946d-3649f38fb8a6
a49540b4-29ce-464f-946d-3649f38fb8a6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Gen.wrap() and it should work.

So on the first implicit in your sample code you would change it to:

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen

implicit def arbUUID: Arbitrary[UUID] = Arbitrary {
  Gen.wrap(UUID.randomUUID) 
}
```

*Update:* From version `1.13.0`, `wrap` is deprecated, you can use `Gen.delay` instead:

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen

implicit def arbUUID: Arbitrary[UUID] = Arbitrary {
  Gen.delay(UUID.randomUUID) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

From `Scalacheck` version `1.13.0`, you can simply use `Gen.uuid`:

```scala
import org.scalacheck.{Arbitrary, Gen}

implicit def arbUUID: Arbitrary[UUID] = Arbitrary {
        Gen.uuid
    }
```